# оптимизация sql запроса (конкретный случай) нужен разумный баланс

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, оптимизация

Профиль пользователя: вместе с данными пользователя нужно вывести количество постов, комментариев, фоток.

Если бы все было так - то было бы проще, но...

В списке друзей, заблокированных, входящих и исходящих заявок на дружбу также присутствует вывод инфопрофиля пользователей с кол-вом постов, комментариев,..

Я знаю как сделать (уже сделал) один запрос. Но меня напрягает **Using filesort**

```
mysql> explain select  usname,blk_uid,count(uid_posts) from usopt join blist on uid_usopt=blk_uid join posts on uid_posts=blk_uid where uid_blist=1 group by blk_uid; 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blist | ref    | uid_bl,blkd_uid   | uid_bl  | 4       | const             |    2 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | usopt | eq_ref | PRIMARY,uid_usopt | PRIMARY | 4       | mbs.blist.blk_uid |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts | ALL    | NULL              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              |   61 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+---------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

ниже показан вывод из тбл заблокированных пользователей.(и ко-во постов, без комментов и фоток). А если будет подсчитыватся кол-во комментов, фоток то этот запрос будет еще погроможже (будет занимать еще больше ресурсов).

```
mysql> select  usname,blk_uid,count(uid_posts) from usopt join blist on uid_usopt=blk_uid join posts on uid_posts=blk_uid where uid_blist=1 group by blk_uid; 
+---------------------+---------+------------------+
| usname              | blk_uid | count(uid_posts) |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+
| Povierennyy Romanfr |     873 |                3 |
| UserNumber 887      |     887 |                1 |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Можно было бы сделать получение кол-ва постов, комментариев, фоток отдельным запросом, но если на одной странице будет показано 100 друзей пользователя, то, наверное(?!) серверу очень не понравится обрабатывать 100 запросов с одной страницы.Поэтому думаю, что пусть будет лучше один большой, чем сотня мелких.

ааа, вот что еще!: Вывод списка друзей, заблоркированных, входящих и исходящих заявок происходит в цикле. И если отдельно получать для каждого пользователя кол-во постов, комментов, фоток, то это будет **запрос в цикле**.

Можно ли оптимизировать запрос, тот что вверху приведен, (и как это сделать)? Или оставить так как есть и просчитать нагрузку (?) и сделать ограничение на кол-во пользователей... ТА НЕТ. это я какую-то глупость написал: ограничение кол-ва пользователей тут не подходит.

Как оптимизировать запрос (эт я повторяюсь)? Или он не страшен при больших объемах данных?

вот как выглядят пользолватели в списке друзей, заблок, входящ, исходящ заявок.
[image: список пользователей]

вот таблицы:

```
mysql> describe usopt;//опции пользователей
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default                                  | Extra |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+-------+
| uid_usopt     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                                     |       |
| regdate_usopt | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL                                     |       |
| usname        | varchar(32)         | NO   |     | NULL                                     |       |
| usplace       | varchar(32)         | NO   |     |        , ...                             |       |
| usfoto        | varchar(64)         | NO   |     | http:\\foto                              |       |
| sendpm        | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                                        |       |
| r2sh_usopt    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                                     |       |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+-------+


mysql> 

mysql> describe blist;//блэк-лист
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| blist_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid_blist  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| blk_uid    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date_blist | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 

mysql> describe posts;//посты
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pid       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid_posts | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pacc      | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commacc   | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pdate     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ptit      | varchar(128)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pbody     | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

Кажется на данный вопрос (в данный период) не существует верного ответа.Закрываем?

---

2016-10-26 - уже нашел решение.

Comment: Когда на объеме данных испытаете и увидите что тормозит - тогда надо будет задумываться о денормализации данных, т.е. хранить нужные количества прямо в записи пользователя, а не считать каждый раз. Обновлять видимо триггерами. обновления же по идее должны быть реже чем выборки. И/или кешировать данные во всяких memcached. И кстати план выполнения запроса от объема данных может меняться ...

Comment: я уже отредактировал. запрос на получение кол-ва будет в цикле. Ваш ответ я понял (та и сам это как-бэ понимаю), но вот в этом и проблема: не знаю как будет на самом деле. А хочется после не бегать как обос... грязный веник и думать что не так и  как это исправить. Я уже и так знаю слабые места в коде :(. не хочу чтобы их было больше.

Comment: на счет запроса в цикле не понял. вы же в запросе и так используете несколько таблиц, я так понимаю один запрос получит все данные и вы в цикле их получите. Вы же не будете в цикле отдельные запросы на каждой итерации делать

Comment: Два варианта: 1 вариант: один ресурсоемкий запрос (так как я сделал) - получает все  необходимые данные. Разбор данных  и их вывод в цикле. ничего не обычного. 2 вариатн: запрос получает данные (только инфоПрофиль БЕЗ подсчета кол-ва комментов, постов. А потом при разборе данных, ПЕРЕД выводом можно было бы отдельнгым запросом получать кол-во постов комментов..., но все это будет в цикле вывода основной информации. Вот это (получение кол-ва постов, комментов) и будет запросом в цкле.

Comment: второй вариант будет гарантированно хуже

Comment: значит я все правильно сделал (ура!). но еще не полностью дописал код. А оптимизировать запрос никак нельхя?

Comment: Об оптимизации рано говорить. У вас там в этом filesort который вам не нравится участвуют всего 2 записи. А когда их будут тысячи план выполнения может быть другим

Comment: а что может поменяться? Разве есть что-то хуже filesort ? Может я слишком ?  заостряю внимание на запросах.(?)

Comment: когда оптимизатор увидит что данных много он может сделать совершенно другой план, который может оказаться лучше

Answer (score 1):

Только что все решилось (но пока что без написанного кода).

**1** вариант: В тбл usopt добавить несколько полей. При добавлении поста или комментария, увеличивать/уменьшать счетчик кол-ва. Потом без join можно получать кол-во. Но это не соответствует правилам (де-)нормализации.

**2** вариант: создать отдельную тбл для кол-ва постов, комментариев, фоток. При добавл\удал поста, коммента, + или - счетчик, и потом join’oм получать эти количества.

Все оказалось так просто.