# HTTP_REFERER с протоколом https (+подделка)

Tags: php, http, https

Простые вопросы:

Чем опасна подделка HTTP_REFERER ?

Будет ли работать HTTP_REFERER при использовании https протокола ?

---

Использую его следующим образом:На странице профиля пользователя есть кнопки дружбы (заблок, подать заявку, принять в друзья, отменить заявку, прекратить дружбу...). Обработчик дружбы (скрипт) после обработки нажатия кнопки ВОЗВРАЩАЛ на этот самый профиль пользователя.

Но, кнопки дружбы также выводятся в СПИСКЕ друзей, заблокир, вход исход заявок. То есть после нажатия кнопки на стр показа пользователей (не на стр профидля одого пользователя) нужно чтобы обработчик дружбы вернул на страницу показа пользователей (на стр показа друзей, заблок, вхо исход хаявок). Вот у меня по рефереру и делается возврат на нужную страницу.

Я вообще-то как-то подумал  что эту переменную уже удалили из php (примерно месяц без иннтернета был). В не свежей книге нашел хттп_реф., а в инете до сих пор не смотрел.

Переменные которые передаются в реферере жестко промываются. там всего два числовых параметра:

1 какой список выводить (друзья, заблок, вход, исход заявки).

2 парам - номер страницы.

Comment: А зачем вам нужен `HTTP_REFERER`? Вы его в своем коде используете?

Comment: дополнил вопрос. Можно и по другому написать код, но это будет ПЛОХОЙ КОД. Кнопки на стр показа заблокированных видны тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582729/%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мое мнение: лучше **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** не использовать.
Почему: Во многих случаях (даже независимо от пользователя) эта переменная может отсутствовать.

Что делать?
Для **POST** запросов в форме добавьте переменную(ые) по которой(ым) можно однозначно определить url возврата:

```
<input type="hidden" name="prev_url" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($prev_url) ?>" />
```

Для **GET** запросов аналогично добавляем переменную в ссылку перехода.

Но, так как данные проходят через пользователя (браузер), этим данным нельзя доверять. Если переменная на возврат представлена в виде ссылки, то эта ссылка должна вести на ваш сайт. Например так (очень грубый пример проверки):

```
$referrer = 'http://you.site/url_возврата_по_умолчанию/';
if (isset($_POST['prev_url'])) {
    $default_arr = parse_url(strtolower($default_url));
    $prev_arr = parse_url(strtolower($_POST['prev_url']));
    if ($default_arr['host'] == $prev_arr['host']) {
        $referrer = $_POST['prev_url'];
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Вместо url возврата можно использовать сокращенные обозначения, например: `profile-1234`, где `profile` обозначает, что вернутся надо на страницу профиля, а `1234` - что нужна страница профиля юзера под этим номером. **Такие данные легче контролировать чем url.**

Comment: "Для POST запросов в форме добавьте " - форма(ы) абсолютно одинаковые для разных страниц. О добавлении параметра указывающего на стр возврата я думал.... Возможность отключения  в браузерах  отсылку реферера - действительно беда. Провалидировать реферер не сложно. эхх, придется делать разные формы ИЛИ разделить форму на части для динамической вставки метки возврата. Этого я и не хотел делать. У меня формы по reqiure вставляются.

Comment: а как на счет реферера и https ? он будет без особенностей в https работать?

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, ни что вам не мешает перед reqiure вызова формы в определенную переменную прописать данные для возрата, а в форме ее подставить; форма будет одна и та же для всех страниц. Про https: проблем не видел на форуме работающем по https, в пределах форума возрат проходит без проблем.

Comment: только подумал об этом(!) Это же будет просто переменная. А в форме поле <input type="hidden" name="$ref"  и страницу так можно передать.

Comment: прямо на странице, на стороне клиента в форму добавить скрытое поле с данными window.location.href, ну и CSRF не забыть

Comment: яваскрипт вообще не знаю, и не желаю знать - для меня это болотная не интересная муть. На чистом php все решил.