# Узнать где пользователь сайта был ранее

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. При переходе на одну из страниц моего сайта (например `site.ru/game`) идет проверка на авторизацию, и если пользователь не авторизован, его перенаправляет на страницу входа (`site.ru/login`).
Хочу после авторизации проверять историю переходов пользователя:

```
if(страница на уровень ранее == "site.ru/login" && страница на 2 уровня ранее == "site.ru/game") {
  window.location.href="site.ru/game"; // перенаправляем туда, куда он хотел попасть
}
```

С помощью js нашел как узнать на один уровень ранее, это `document.referrer`, но не нашел как получить страницу на 2 уровня ранее. Хотелось бы без использования сторонних библиотек. Если это нельзя сделать, то возможно с помощью PHP можно это сделать. Понимаю что пользователь может использовать режим инкогнито, где браузер ничего нам не даст, но для меня это не важно.

Comment: Получить данные истории браузера нельзя. Она защищена из соображений сохранения персональных данных пользователя. От включения режима инкогнито это не зависит.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583000/186083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юзайте **COOKIE** , смотрите, идея такова. Что когда пользователь переходит на страницу вашу страницу запускается мини алгоритм кук. Если кука есть значит пользователь пришел из нашего сайта, с определённой страницы. Если нет, то установить ее.

Тоесть открыл пользователь index.php.

1.Если куки нет, поставить ее .

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['old']) == false){
         setcookie('old', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

2. Если кука есть, то мы знаем на какой странице пользователь был!

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['old']) == false){
          setcookie('old', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}else {
          echo 'Ты пришел из '.$_COOKIE['old'];
}
```

***!!!Warning***  Делайте setcookie еще до использования echo. Иначе получите падение. Это связано с ограничением самого формата http. Или юзайте буферы (ob_start(); , ob_end_flush());

**ob_start** - включает буферизацию вывода.

**ob_end_flush** - очищает (отправляет) буфер вывода и отключает буферизацию вывода.

Comment: Так я узнаю откуда он пришел, но мне нужно узнать где был до этого. После авторизации прошлой страницей будет всегда страница входа, а мне нужно узнать какая страница была у пользователя до страницы входа, и если это нужная мне страница, только тогда перенаправить на нее же.

Comment: "была у пользователя до страницы входа" getenv("HTTP_REFERER") попробуйте. Правда не люблю такое и не все сайты оставляют такой заголовок.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 1):

Используйте параметры *HTTP* запроса

1. Пользователь запрашивает страницу `site.ru/game`.
   Сервер определяет, что пользователь не авторизован, и перенаправляет на страницу входа, добавив в параметры исходную страницу

   ```
   302
   Location: site.ru/login?return_url=game
   ```
2. Браузер обрабатывает ответ `302`, отправляет запрос на `site.ru/login?return_url=game`.
   Сервер рендерит страницу входа. Далее есть два варианта: ничего не делать или добавить `return_url` в `<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="game">`.
   Возвращает страницу пользователю.
3. Пользователь вводит логин и пароль, отправляет *POST* запрос.
   Сервер авторизует пользователя, ищет в параметрах *URL* или в данных *POST* (смотря какой вариант мы выбрали) `return_url` и осуществляет перенаправление

   ```
   302
   Location: site.ru/game
   ```

Comment: На странице входа у меня есть кнопка "регистрация", при нажатии на нее к адресу добавляется например `site.ru/login#signup`, то есть если пользователь не зарегистрирован, он нажимает кнопку регистрация и тот параметр откуда пришел пользователь пропадет.